# What Excel function to categorize, sort or lookup values within a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, pivot-table

I am trying to create a workbook (non-VBA) for collating materials required for student experiments. At the moment, I have a list of all the experiments and their materials. Below is a excerpt of the table.

[image: Screenshot of Experiment table]
Each column has unique data except for Chapter (there are two textbooks that repeat chapters 1-14). The materials are separated by a line-break (alt+enter) in the cell. However, if easier, this could be changed to distinct columns (i.e. Material 1, Material 2, etc.).

As mention at the beginning, I am trying to find a way to collate the materials required, how many are required and the experiment they are required for. I am vaguely aware that the answer might be pivot tables, but I am not sure how to achieve this - or even if it is possible.

[*IF that is possible*, I would also try and incorporate another table with the material and what room if would be found in.]

Comment: text to columns maybe?

Comment: If I wanted all the materials in separate columns, I could do that. However, it doesn't really solve anything, that is all.

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually:

- Use Power Query (Get & Transform) to load the data.
- Split the materials column into multiple columns
- Normalize the table by using the Unpivot Other Columns, while the Unit column is selected
- Load the result into the worksheet

Now you can build a pivot table based on the Power Query result table, because all the materials will be in a single column.

Comment: That is all very interesting. I had no idea such a thing (Power Query/Get & Transform) existed. I am a little unsure how I might create a Pivot Table from this.